# TypeError: <class 'wtforms.validators.InputRequired'> is not a valid validator because it is a class, it should be an instance

Tags: python, html, authentication, flask, wtforms

I'm currently following a tutorial by Arpan Neupane called "Python Flask Authentication Tutorial - Learn Flask Login" so that I can authentication working on my website. I'm using Python, SQL, and HTML pages in flask to build it. I've been following the code exactly as he said(though I have extra code for other aspects of my website)

Despite our code being identical, I get an issue with wtforms. Specifically the InputRequired form. Upon running my code I receive this error message:
"TypeError: <class 'wtforms.validators.InputRequired'> is not a valid validator because it is a class, it should be an instance"

Here is my code

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, url_for, request, session
from flask_session import Session
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import UserMixin, LoginManager
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Length, ValidationError

# Configure application
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
db = SQLAlchemy()
db.init_app(app)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'lunamoonpie'

# Create user class which stores user info
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)

# Create a registry form for users to sign up
class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField(validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=20)], render_kw={"placeholder": "Username"})
    password = PasswordField(validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=20)], render_kw={"placeholder": "Password"})
    submit = SubmitField("Register")

    # Validate username by checking if it's already taken
    def check_username(self, username):
        if User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first():
            raise ValidationError("Username already in use")
        
# Create a login form for users to login
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField(validators=[InputRequired, Length(min=4, max=20)], render_kw={"placeholder": "Username"})
    password = PasswordField(validators=[InputRequired, Length(min=4, max=20)], render_kw={"placeholder": "Password"})
    submit = SubmitField("Login")

# Register for a new account
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
   form = RegisterForm()
   return render_template("register.html", form=form)
```

My HTML file also looks like this:

```
<body style="text-align: center">
    <div>
        Register below
    </div>
    <div style="padding-top: 10%;">
        <form action="/register" method="post">
            {{ form.username }}
            {{ form.password }}
            {{ form.submit }}
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I can't help but wonder if it's an issue with wtforms updating or something like that. I've checked dozens of times for syntax errors but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to add the ```()``` after ```InputRequired``` in the LoginForm() block.

Comment: Yep, that was it

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I'm an idiot. When I first saw this error, I went back to RegisterForm and fixed InputRequired to InputRequired(). When I continued seeing the error, I thought there was some other issue, but I actually had just forgot that InputRequired is being used in the LoginForm as well.  :{

It works now that I've added the () to InputRequired.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).